# Laravel Class mailer does not exist

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I updated my application from 5 to 5.2. Now when I call Mail::send() it return an exception Class mailer does not exist.

```
Mail::send('emails.mail', ['data' => $content], function ($m) use ($to, $subject,$toname) {

            $m->to($to, $toname)->subject($subject);


        });
```

When I open Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail class there is only one function

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'mailer';
}
```

Please help. If anyone have any idea

Comment: Did you run a `composer update`?

Comment: please run composer cache-clear ,    composer dump-autoload,  composer update

Comment: @rap-2-h Yes i updated. But no use :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution
just put `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,` in app.php providers

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `php artisan config:clear` must be run in order to get rid of that kind of errors ("Class mailer does not exist").

I've migrated my project 1:1 (code, config, vhost) from old laptop to new one (Windows->Ubuntu) and I couldn't run the app without clearing config's cache.

Comment: What if running `php artisan config:clear` just repeats the error instead of clearing the config?

Comment: This is an old post but this could help someone, my problemas was a parameter that I was incluiding in EventServiceProvider.php  in trying to capture every login event, so the error could just be somwhere where you are not looking!

Answer (score 2):

Check where is you call \Debugbar::enable();, it happens when you enable debugbar in register method of service provider.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to delete the files in `bootstrap/cache` and run `composer update`.