# ReflectionException: Class mailer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

If I use `\mail` in a test class, Laravel 5.7 tells me that class `mailer`does not exists.

Here is my test function:

```
/**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
      \Mail::raw('Hello world', function($message){
        $message->to('foo@bar.com');
        $message->from('bar@foo.com');
      });

    }
```

This happens when I enter `phpunit` in terminal:

> 1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest ReflectionException: Class
>   mailer does not exist
>
> /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:658
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:609
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:735
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1222
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:175
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:144
>   /home/www/testmachine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:231
>   /home/www/testmachine/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:14

However, when I use mail somewhere else in my application it works, for example in `Route.php`:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
  \Mail::raw('Hello world', function($message){
    $message->to('foo@bar.com');
    $message->from('bar@foo.com');
  });
  dd('hi');
});
```

I checked that `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class` is in app.php as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504227/2311074) and I also performed a `composer update` and then `composer dump-autoload` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476236/2311074).

Any ideas why this error is thrown?

Comment: Do you actually want to send mail from your test or do you want to fake sending mail?

Answer (score 1):

In the test class, I think you'll need to specify the Mail class up top with a use statement:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

But check out the mail faking abilities (`Mail::fake()`) before you get too far with your testing.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#mail-fake

Comment: I tried to specify it with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;` and use `Mail::` instead of `\Mail` but I get the same error message. Thank you for mentioning the faker class.

Answer (score 0):

For mocking the mails, just check this docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#mail-fake

But for sending actual mails you can use MailTrap test classes written by laracasts

https://github.com/laracasts/Behat-Laravel-Extension#service-mailtrap

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, during a `composer dump-autoload`. It turned out that I had a simple syntax error somewhere in my code, and I also have set up an exception handler that sends me an email any time an error is thrown on the site.

What I think happened is that during the `composer dump-autoload`, Composer hadn't built its `autoload` file when the syntax error was encountered, so when this triggered the email to me, the `Mail` facade call failed, even with the correct `use` statement.

Probably not a widespread cause for this error, but hopefully this will be of use to someone.